# PostgreSQL select Data where Array is in array

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql

I have an database like this.

```
vendors
id    title        
1    'Papa Johns'
2    'Google'
```

I have an `starred` array that could look like this:
`[1]`
or
`[1, 2]`

I want to write a query which selects everything in the starred array, this is what I tried:

`SELECT * FROM vendors WHERE vendors.id IN [1, 2]`

But that gave a syntax error, I'm not sure of the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use integer constans, [use IN:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#functions-comparisons-in-scalar)

```
SELECT * 
FROM vendors 
WHERE vendors.id IN (1, 2);
```

Alternatively, you can use [ANY(array):](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#idm46046882500112)

```
SELECT * 
FROM vendors 
WHERE vendors.id = ANY(array[1, 2]);
```